# Should multilingual posts be edited to remove non-English content?

Tags: discussion, languages, non-english-speakers, english

I've noticed a few posts that presumably contain the same content in both English and a secondary language (most frequently Spanish).

Sometimes the English translations are contributed by the OP in the original revision:

> [RETURNING id problem with insert Postgres 8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380835/returning-id-problem-with-insert-postgres-8-4)
>
> [term by term division in python (division termino a termino en python )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785005/term-by-term-division-in-python-division-termino-a-termino-en-python)

Occasionally a translation of the original post is later added:

> [Integracion de Zend Framework con Propel [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760591/integracion-de-zend-framework-con-propel)

In the last example, I'm not sure whether the question was closed due to its original lack of English content or due to its lack of a real question. (Note that I'm *not* asking [how we should handle (monolingual) non-English content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/how-should-we-handle-non-english-answers) in general; I merely linked this question because it fits the multilingual pattern.)

If Stack Exchange's official language is English, should the non-English content of such posts be removed via edits, or is the multilingual content acceptable so long as English is represented in parallel?

Comment: This has [already been discussed in parts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85158/should-non-english-questions-have-a-link-to-a-translator).

Comment: Hmm, Spanish is close to English though.. just a thought

Comment: @Adel They have more in common than English and non-Indo-European languages, but English isn't particularly close to Spanish within that group. English is a Germanic language and Spanish is a Romance language.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes. Remove non-English content.

- We can't easily verify the content and meaning
- We can't keep it in sync if we edit the English part
- [Stack Overflow is an English-speaking community](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

Answer (score 4):

When someone has a clear question is some language not English (which is what's used on SE) and has a translation to English: I'd fix the translation and leave the original.  Maybe someone bi-lingual will see that the translation is a bit wrong, or some subtlety has been missed.

If there is a lot of other language, and a really poor (incomprehensible) translation: I'd probably flag it as too poor.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is willing to do the work of providing a translation, then it should be allowed to stay.  As long as they have a clear question in English, then it's not hurting anything to have a translation in another language alongside.

Note, the English should be first, so that's what's seen in the excerpt.