# Flagging non-English questions

Tags: discussion, flags, english

So, this is a new one...

*[Mac OS X 10.6.8 to Mac OS X 10.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520500/mac-os-x-10-6-8-to-mac-os-x-10-7-0)* (later translated from German to English and then deleted)

In the interest of accuracy, how should this question be flagged? It's my understanding that Stack Overflow is an English website, and that multi-language support was canned as not feasible.

Comment: So [@bart](http://stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart) has gone ahead and [translated it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11520500/revisions) for the OP.  Drastic edit but yea... :P

Comment: @Lix - So now I am _certain_ it is off-topic.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry about that. Couldn't resist. It's off-topic indeed.

Comment: Duplicate? [Should multilingual posts be edited to remove non-English content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109048/136489)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I normally vote to close these as too localized.

As for flagging - if you feel the need to flag, then this would be an "Other" flag explaining to the moderators that the post is not in English.

There is no point in voting "Off-topic" for migration as if this will normally end up on another Stack Exchange site where chances are it will get closed pretty quickly (unless it is happens to belong, though for most questions asked in a language that is not English, this is unlikely).

If you do have the language skills to *translate* the question to English, that would probably be best, even if it does end up migrated to another site.

Comment: I don't believe I have enough rep for the 'Vote to Close' option, unless it's hiding somewhere that I'm not seeing.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - No, you don't have the rep for it yet. See the Stack Overflow [Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) page.

Comment: The asker's German skills weren't good, either …

Comment: @Kay - I am not in a position to judge that. If it were in Hebrew, that would be a different matter ;)

Comment: Off-topic doesn't necessarily mean that it belongs on another Stack Exchange site - it just means that it doesn't belong where it is.

Comment: Answers here say to *not* translate posts to english: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#comment659764_297673

Comment: I did as suggested here for this question and the flag was declined

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivCLi.png)

Answer (score 4):

I would flag (or vote to close) as "Off Topic", since part of the parameters of what can be discussed on Stack Overflow requires the post be in English.

Comment: Which subtype of "Off Topic" should be used? None of them seem to quite fit.

Answer (score -3):

I have always thought non-English questions should use a language tag. In this case: `[DE]`. And have the users ignoring languages different than theirs.

But that was long discussed and rejected :)

Comment: I've been thinking about this concept, despite the fact that I'm aware of the fact that it will never happen.... the first big problem that I can see would be the fact you would need mods fluent in all languages....

Comment: @mikeTheLiar You're totally right. I think there weren't any community moderator back when I first proposed this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/add-meta-tag-to-support-internationalization