# Translating Posts into other languages

Tags: feature-request, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization: The state of the nation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation)
>   [Automatic translator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92698/automatic-translator)

> **See also:**
>
> [We need to help non-English-speakers somehow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8162/152657)

Could we have some sort of 'translating mechanism'? This could prevent proposals like [this](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1234/1299) from having to be created.

Some implementation ideas:

- Users who speak a different language could go to *es.stackoverflow*, etc where StackOverflow pages are translated to Spanish.
- WOT style 'translate button'.

Google Translate is pretty accurate... at least, for simple posts in well known/similar languages. (i.e. English<->French) This way, we won't have to have duplicate questions across the 'different language but same subject' sites.

(SE *can* use the Google Translate API, right?)

Comment: [Provide some kind of on-the-fly translation - E.g. French to English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42544/provide-some-kind-of-on-the-fly-translation-e-g-french-to-english), [Automatic translator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92698/automatic-translator), [Why don't they just make SO multilingual? It's possible!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/why-dont-they-just-make-so-multilingual-its-possible), [Should non-English questions have a link to a translator?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85158/should-non-english-questions-have-a-link-to-a-translator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have difficulty reconciling Google Translated questions with a paid CHAOS team going round *improving* the quality of the existing English-language questions. There's enough human-generated low-quality English on SO as it stands, without adding computer-generated low-quality [foreign-language].

I understand the motivation, but I'm skeptical about the chances of it working. If people want an automatically-translated-but-low-quality version of SO in their own language, they can use Chrome...

Comment: @Pop, well to be honest, I *assumed* they were paid, but I guess they might not be. (After all, **we** aren't!)

Comment: Oh, they're employees, I'm sure they're getting paid. It was supposed to be a joke.